# Django. Меняющееся количество чекбоксов в зависимости от базы данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Имеем дело с Django 4. Имеется ListView, который передаёт на страницу массив моделей из базы данных.

views.py

```
class Menu(GetSessionFilterMixin, FormMixin, ListView):
    model = Dish
    template_name = "visitor/menu.html"
    context_object_name = "dishes"

    def get_queryset(self) -> QuerySet[Any]:
        return Dish.objects.filter(isavailable=True)
```

menu.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Меню</title>    
</head>
<body>
    {% for dish in dishes %}
    <p>{{ dish }}</p> <!-- вот условно тут должен быть чекбокс -->
    {% endfor %}
    <!-- тут кнопка отправить -->
</body>
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы у каждого элемента выводился чекбокс рядом, а снизу кнопка, при нажатии на которую, отправлялся бы post запрос с выбранными чекбоксами на определённый url, который бы всё это дело уже обрабатывал.

Загвоздка именно в том, чтобы пришвартовать к каждому элементу чекбокс, при условии, что этих элементов может быть разное количество, а кнопка отправки должна быть для всех одна.

Есть мысль сделать это как-то через форму (пытался разобраться, как это в админке джанго работает, но не получилось), но не дошло.

Можете, пожалуйста, подсказать, или подкинуть каких-нибудь идей?

Заранее, благодарю

Comment: Наверное [ModelMultipleChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField) и [CheckboxSelectMultiple](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/widgets/#checkboxselectmultiple)

Comment: @andreymal да, я тоже так думаю, однако вот как состыковать это и с БД, чтобы не делать все сколько бы то ни было полей просто `display: none;`, и как кнопку подтверждения...

Answer (score 1):

В общем, не знаю, насколько изящное решение, но сделал следующее: создал форму с `forms.MultipleChoiceField`, но `choices` не указывал. Далее используем родительский конструктор, а только после - указываем значение `choices` у нашего `forms.MultipleChoiceField`. Порядок обязателен: родительский конструктор -> инстанцирование `choices` (до этого не мог дойти долго).

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class ToOrderForm(forms.Form):
    choices = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
    )

    def __init__(self, orders, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ToOrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['choices'].choices = [(order.id, order) for order in orders]
```

В классе-представлении указываем `form_class = ToOrderForm`, также переопределяем

```
def get_form_kwargs(self) -> Dict[str, Any]:
    kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs['orders'] = ... # тут ваша логика
    return kwargs
```

И уже в темплейте используем через ключевое слово `{{ form }}`

```
    <form action="{% url 'your:url' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for f in form %}
            {{ f }}
        {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit">Подвердить</button>
    </form>
```